# display user error without viewmodel

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, error-handling, modelstate

So how do i easiest display the user error on the view without a connected viewmodel?

in my view im using a upload like this:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary()


            @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
                  .Name("files")
                  .Async(a => a
                      .Save("CompanyLogoSave", "Company")
                      .AutoUpload(true)
                              )
                  )

        }
```

that post the value to my controller and if its not a an image i do this

```
    else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "You can only upload images!");
                    ViewData.Add("UploadError", "You can only upload images!");
                    return View("Logo", files);
                }
```

And i've tried about 10 different ways to display the error on my view:

```
    @if (ViewBag.UploadError != null)
    {
     <div>
      @ViewBag.UploadError
    </div>
    }
```

or

```
 @{
 if(!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
   <script>
      alert(@ViewBad.UploadError)
   </script>
 }
```

i've also tried to call this js when the upload gets an error

```
 <script>
        function showAlertWindow(e) {
            console.log(e);
            var alertWindow = $('#alertWindow').data('kendoWindow');
            alertWindow.content(error_handler(e));
            alertWindow.refresh();
            alertWindow.center();
            alertWindow.open();
        }
        function getFileInfo(e) {
            return $.map(e.files, function (file) {
                var info = file.name;

                // File size is not available in all browsers
                if (file.size > 0) {
                    info += " (" + Math.ceil(file.size / 1024) + " KB)";
                }
                return info;
            }).join(", ");
        }

        function error_handler(e) {

            if (e.errors) {
                alert("2");
                var message = "Errors:\n <ul>";
                $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                    console.log("3");
                    if ('errors' in value) {
                        $.each(value.errors, function () {
                            message += "<li>" + this + "</li>";
                        });
                    }
                });
                showAlertWindow(message + "</ul>");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

but without any luck.

Comment: That doesn't looks like `C#` to me. Tagging correctly is important to get answers.

Comment: @Sinatr this is MVC and C#. In the second code-box there is a part of my controller method where i first check if the input of the upload is a image and if it's not i go to that else part. The other parts is the view code where i want to show the error ive made in my controller method